# How to learn Sanskrit from scratch?

Tags: sanskrit, language, resource

Is there any resource to learn Sanskrit which uses no other language other than Sanskrit?

It may seem like paradox but I want to learn Sanskrit in most natural way which involves no translations. 
One solution could be the way kids are taught any language in first days by teachers but the case mentioned is different here as I want to learn the language on my own.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hinduism.StackExchange. There are many excellent Youtube Videos where they teach Sanskrit speaking through spoken Sanskrit. you can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLudSN7Po9muLeRM6545s68eakbxwZRpEJ) out for instance. I advise you to consider buying some of the basic Samaskrita Bharati books as well which can be used to clarify doubts when learning from these videos.

Comment: Thanks for great resource but I would like to prefer some online text based resource as the only device I possess is an e-reader.

Comment: IMHO, i think it's impossible to learn a language using that language alone when you can't listen to the language being spoken. Also, do you know how to read Sanskrit script?

Comment: I know Devanagari since Hindi language  is my mother tongue. Besides confusion may arise therefore I want to clarify that I am normal person not isolated but having adequate  information of external world.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find anything online like a picture book that can be used with e-reader. Better to approach through Spoken Sanskrit Videos on YouTube like the link in my first comment since you want to learn it without help of any other language.

Comment: @SreeCharan This is like saying that you will close a question on mathematical notation in Math.SE because it is not about Mathematics.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing out preexisting similar question, but I could nowhere find my answer there. Difference is I want to learn Sanskrit without keep on learning synonyms of another language and the question pointed asks for the best language to start learning Sanskrit.

Comment: For those calling it off topic, please suggest the appropriate stack exchange site to ask questions about Sanskrit language or may be should call to create new site EXCLUSIVE to Sanskrit if it seems to've no relationship with Hindu religion.

Comment: I understand your problem. A call for Sanskrit.SE was already made and was deleted due to lack of followers. It is [started again](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language) by another user. If you are interested in it, follow the proposal and add example questions in it.A separate site takes a lot of time and patience. Yes, Hinduism is related to Sanskrit very much. We encourage Sanskrit questions which ask about interpretation of shlokas and our scriptures. Only *pure language,translation and grammar questions are closed as off-topic*.